# How to run a javascript on a browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I actually created a javascript to get a plot of statistics of my assembled genome : here is the name of my script: myscript.js

And here is its containt:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>assembly stats</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/circle-plot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/square-plot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/table.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/circle-plot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/square-plot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
    <div id="assembly_stats">
    <script charset="utf-8" src="d3.js"></script>
    <script>
      d3.json("json/Danaus_plexippus_v3.assembly-stats.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) return console.warn(error);
        asm = new Assembly (json);
        asm.drawPlot('assembly_stats');
      })
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and when I try to run by doing: `node my_script.js`, I get:

```
/Users/etudiant/Cov_genome/my_script.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <html>
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:646:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
```

Does someone know where is the problem? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Your "script" is an HTML file, not a script. HTML is for browsers, not for node.

Comment: Your file is called `my_script.js`, but it looks like it's actually a "full-blown" HTML page. That's not something you should run via `node`. Rename your `my_script.js` to `my_script.html` and try your luck running it inside an actual browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run it in a browser, you need to load the HTML document with a browser (and it should have a `.html` file extension, not a `.js` file extension.

Node.JS is not a browser. You are getting that error message because you are telling it to interpret HTML as if it were JavaScript.

Use something like Chrome, Firefox, or Edge instead.

If you want to initiate things using Node, then consider a module like [Node Webdriver](http://webdriver.io/) which will let you drive a browser from Node.

Comment: what he said - this is your answer, OP

Comment: @DMcCallum83 — That's what I said in the first paragraph of this answer.

Comment: sorry @Quentin I didn't mean to post that after i spent more than a second looking at your answer.

Comment: Thanks, i did it but I actually get nothing on the webpage, it's empty, do you know why?

Comment: @Benjamin — Most likely because the URLs don't resolve correctly. Check the Console and Network tabs of the developer tools in the browser.